# Tcl: How do I call a proc from a different namespace, while also passing my proc a variable from its namespace?

Tags: scope, namespaces, tcl

I've got two scripts defined: the first script calls a proc in the second script.  The second script defines a namespace `fooSpace`, defines a variable `fooValue` within `fooSpace`, and defines a proc `myProc` within `fooSpace` as well.

In my first script, I want to call my proc with an argument of `myValue`.  I want my proc to test if `myValue` exists in `fooSpace` as `fooValue`.  If so, the function will use `fooValue` to do some stuff.

If I understand correctly, `upvar` references the caller's namespace, which in my case is not the same as the function's namespace.  But I don't think I can do `variable $myvalue` within my proc, either, right?  How do I get my proc to use a variable defined in `fooSpace`?

My code below returns "Can't read $fooSpace"

Here's what my first script (located in alpha.tcl) looks like:

```
source bravo.tcl
namespace import fooSpace::myProc

# call the fuction
myProc apples
```

Here's what my second script (located in bravo.tcl) looks like:

```
namespace eval fooSpace {
    namespace export myProc
    set apples "Apples are 3 for a dollar"

    proc myProc {myValue} {
        upvar $fooSpace::$myValue fruit
        if {[info exists fruit] == 1} {
            puts "$fruit"
        } else {
            puts "we don't have any $fruit today"
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls. try to improve your question wording and examples. (a) the examples are not minimal (e.g. `source` is not needed to demonstrate the perceived issue); (b) they are not functional (`myfunction` vs. `myProc`), (c) you do not report the correct wording of the error messages reported to you: `Can't read $fooSpace` is not a Tcl error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want using `namespace upvar`, which is designed for looking at variables in another namespace:

```
namespace upvar $fooSpace $myValue fruit
```

Alternatively, you can use `upvar` to do it, but then you need to stop the substitution of the `fooSpace` variable name from including the namespace separator afterwards (or you end up talking about the variable with the empty name within that namespace, which probably doesn't exist). This control of quoting is done with `${…}` like this:

```
upvar ${fooSpace}::$myValue fruit
```

(You could use `${fooSpace}::${myValue}` too, it'd all work the same after parsing.)

I recommend that you use `namespace upvar` though: it's quite a bit more efficient because it doesn't have to reparse variable names at all.

Comment: The `namespace upvar` command was created to accelerate the Snit package (in Tcllib) which uses variables taken from another variably-named namespace a lot in its implementation. It's quite a lot faster than ordinary `upvar` and string manipulation, especially when you're importing multiple variables from the same namespace.

Comment: Hi Donal.  `namespace_upvar` was exactly what I was looking for for my Tcl 8.7 application.  I just found out that the bench where I'll be running my code is actually using Tcl 8.4, however.  Any ideas how I would get the same code above to work with that version? (I'm not sure if I should revise my original question since the answer is definitely relevant, ask a new question, or ask in the comments).  Open to direction/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get my proc to use a variable defined in fooSpace?

Your use of `upvar` is bogus, you miss the level argument, `#0`:

```
upvar "#0" [namespace current]::$myValue fruit
```

In addition, `$fooSpace` is not referencing the namespace `fooSpace`, but a proc-local variable of that name (hence the `can't read "fooSpace": no such variable` error); therefore:

```
[namespace current]::$myValue
```

which turns into

```
::fooSpace::$myValue
```

> But I don't think I can do variable $myvalue within my proc, either

It depends, if you want to work with a link variable `fruit`, no, the `variable` command won't give you that. But you can certainly reference namespaced variables like this:

```
 variable $myValue
```

Minor suggestion: `myValue` would be better coined `myVar` or `myVarName` because the argument denotes (namespaced) variable *names* (not values stored by these variables).